# Deleting Millions of Documents in cosmos in a reasonable amount of time

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Recently I have been working a lot with Cosmos and ran in to an issue when looking at deleting documents.

I need to delete around ~40 million documents in my Cosmos Container, I've looked around quite a bit and found a few options of which i have tried. two of the fastest of which I've tried are using a stored procedure within cosmos to delete records and using a bulk executor.

Both of these options have given subpar results compared to what I am looking for. I believe this should be obtainable within a couple hours but at the moment I am getting performance of around 1 hour per million recordsT

the two methods I used can also be seen here:

[Stack Overflow Post on Document Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500704/how-to-bulk-delete-say-millions-of-documents-spread-across-millions-of-logical)

My documents are about 35 keys long where half are string values and the other half are float/integer values, if that matters, and there are around 100k records per partition.

Here is are the two examples that I am using to attempt the deletion:

This first one is using C# and the documentation that helped me with this is here:

[GitHub Documentation azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor;
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.BulkImport;
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.BulkDelete;

namespace BulkDeleteSample
{
    class Program
    {

        private static readonly string EndpointUrl = "xxxx";
        private static readonly string AuthorizationKey = "xxxx";
        private static readonly string DatabaseName = "xxxx";
        private static readonly string CollectionName = "xxxx";


        static ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp
        };


        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey, connectionPolicy);
            DocumentCollection dataCollection = GetCollectionIfExists(client, DatabaseName, CollectionName);

            // Set retry options high during initialization (default values).
            client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30;
            client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 9;

            BulkExecutor bulkExecutor = new BulkExecutor(client, dataCollection);
            await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync();

            // Set retries to 0 to pass complete control to bulk executor.
            client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 0;
            client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 0;

            List<Tuple<string, string>> pkIdTuplesToDelete = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
            {
                pkIdTuplesToDelete.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1", i.ToString()));
            }

            BulkDeleteResponse bulkDeleteResponse = await bulkExecutor.BulkDeleteAsync(pkIdTuplesToDelete);

        }

        static DocumentCollection GetCollectionIfExists(DocumentClient client, string databaseName, string collectionName)
        {

            return client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseName))
                .Where(c => c.Id == collectionName).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

The second one is using a stored procedure I found which delete data from a given partition using a query, of which I am running via a python notebook.

Here is the stored procedure:

```py
/**
 * A Cosmos DB stored procedure that bulk deletes documents for a given query.
 * Note: You may need to execute this sproc multiple times (depending whether the sproc is able to delete every document within the execution timeout limit).
 *
 * @function
 * @param {string} query - A query that provides the documents to be deleted (e.g. "SELECT c._self FROM c WHERE c.founded_year = 2008"). Note: For best performance, reduce the # of properties returned per document in the query to only what's required (e.g. prefer SELECT c._self over SELECT * )
 * @returns {Object.<number, boolean>} Returns an object with the two properties:
 *   deleted - contains a count of documents deleted
 *   continuation - a boolean whether you should execute the sproc again (true if there are more documents to delete; false otherwise).
 */
function bulkDeleteSproc(query) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var responseBody = {
        deleted: 0,
        continuation: true
    };

    // Validate input.
    if (!query) throw new Error("The query is undefined or null.");

    tryQueryAndDelete();

    // Recursively runs the query w/ support for continuation tokens.
    // Calls tryDelete(documents) as soon as the query returns documents.
    function tryQueryAndDelete(continuation) {
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
                // Begin deleting documents as soon as documents are returned form the query results.
                // tryDelete() resumes querying after deleting; no need to page through continuation tokens.
                //  - this is to prioritize writes over reads given timeout constraints.
                tryDelete(retrievedDocs);
            } else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; repeat the query w/ the token.
                tryQueryAndDelete(responseOptions.continuation);
            } else {
                // Else if there are no more documents and no continuation token - we are finished deleting documents.
                responseBody.continuation = false;
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        });

        // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    }

    // Recursively deletes documents passed in as an array argument.
    // Attempts to query for more on empty array.
    function tryDelete(documents) {
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            // Delete the first document in the array.
            var isAccepted = collection.deleteDocument(documents[0]._self, {}, function (err, responseOptions) {
                if (err) throw err;

                responseBody.deleted++;
                documents.shift();
                // Delete the next document in the array.
                tryDelete(documents);
            });

            // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
            if (!isAccepted) {
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        } else {
            // If the document array is empty, query for more documents.
            tryQueryAndDelete();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am doing anything wrong or it the performance just isn't there with cosmos but I'm finding it quite difficult to achieve what I'm looking for, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the TTL to zero instead of deleting them immediately?

Comment: would updating the documents be much faster than deleting them? i can try this but I'm skeptical of the performance gains.

Comment: There is no bulk delete, and a stored procedure will only delete within a logical partition. Perhaps it's more efficient to preserve data you want to keep, into another collection (via changefeed or some other mechanism), and then delete the original collection?

Comment: @toubi: I think it would depend. At the least, it wouldn't have to update indexes as part of that call.

Comment: If you want to delete entire partitions, this feature is in preview. Might be worth getting involved to try it for your case: https://aka.ms/cosmosPkDeleteSignup

Comment: Thanks ill take a look into this preview, see if it can help me out here